# missing a specfic library for upload photo in android

Tags: android

I found this [tutorial](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/android-custom-gallery-and-instant-upload-project/#comment-1280) and I tried running it so I can put it on my own project.

I want to put an upload from gallery button on my app. My app already has a running capture image and this is what I'm missing but I got this error:

```
D:\Vikas\Downloads\httpcomponents-client-4.1-beta1-bin-with-dependencies\httpcomponents-client-4.1-beta1\lib\httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar
```

It is a library missing error. Any help on how to fix it or any other suggestions like tutorials would be much appreciated.

Comment: down load the required jars from here http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Comment: thank you for the fast response il go work on it there are no jar in there